# iOS app review using gmail login stuck at promt "Verify is you"

Tags: ios, gmail, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am writing an app for getting and showing Admob Reports in the app, using Admob API.

But when submitting to iOS Reviewer they need an account for reviewing then I provide my account.
But when they login to the Google account I provide, Google shows a dialog that confirms that "Verify is you" that needs action on my side (Pixel 6 phone).
[image]

How can I bypass this dialog? How can an ios reviewer review my app?

My review was stuck for a week, please help me.

Many thanks,